# Need help adding 2FA to my login page with Microsoft authenticator app

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, two-factor-authentication

Adding 2FA Microsoft login authenticator app in my Asp.net framework 4.8

[image: But I got this error]

I added Access-Control-Allow-Origin in IIS HTTP response header but didn't work
I added

```
// Check if the request is an OPTIONS request (preflight request)
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

to my global.asax.cs Application_BeginRequest but didn't work

My startup.cs looks like this

```
   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //ConfigureAuth(app);
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            OwinTokenAcquirerFactory factory = TokenAcquirerFactory.GetDefaultInstance<OwinTokenAcquirerFactory>();

            app.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(factory);
            factory.Services
                .Configure<ConfidentialClientApplicationOptions>(options => { options.RedirectUri = "https://localhost:9636/"; })
                .AddMicrosoftGraph()
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
            factory.Build();
        }
```

I added in my HomeController

```
if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                        new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                        OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                }
```

and i added all the packages needed and still getting the issue that the  Access to XMLHttpRequest is blocked by CORS policy

> localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/e7df06a6-1701-4f2b-be2c-49600242e7b5/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=eae94e6f-cf47-4bb3-bfac-0a7e51eba0fc&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access%20user.read&code_challenge=1MXkJ5MZ2-crU4p9PB2I_UJ7d6PnGJ28F_UX_UNi2L8&code_challenge_method=S256&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3DcCIlRhbupLgv0clV0dGjCJKhbOFABFY57YcFPElJu4cMfLJObi_2JJ2U0qxk6_KhcTtLh5oIez4OxpRGNLP63xPzOlM2ENniA2Jb7Y-5oANeH8406IK3-7Qn1MhMqJBKkrpCsQ3C0n8eSSLPTDKSbxLPpsJv2WueRDssTQoTeUQ&response_mode=form_post&nonce=638209413582599616.ZDAwZmI1OTEtYTZiOS00MjFkLThmMDctOTJhNzQwZjg3NmNkMGJjNTJlMWYtZThhOC00M2E5LWEzOWYtYjgxMDJkYmMzZmU2&client_info=1&x-client-brkrver=IDWeb.2.10.0.0&x-client-SKU=ID_NET472&x-client-ver=6.30.0.0' (redirected from 'https://localhost/...../') from origin 'https://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.